# HTML5 canvas javascript brush not equal in other scale

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi i have brush **Sketchy** who use random function. With it i drawing on two layers first layer original size and second layer 2x bigger. In both layers i painting same drawings. At first glance u can't see any difference, but then i click button **"Clear and insert backup in first square"** this button just copy from second layer to first with original scale and u can see at this moment how change drawings. Because first layer not equal second layer.

```js
/* Layer 1 */
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* Layer 2 */
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctxBigger = canvas2.getContext('2d');

var coords = {};
var pencil = {};
var isDrawing = false;
var TwoTimesBigger = 2;



function getMousePosInCanvas(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

$('#canvas').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  coords = getMousePosInCanvas(canvas, e);  
  isDrawing = true; 
  pencil.setPreviousCoords(coords.x, coords.y);
});

$('#canvas').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(isDrawing) {
    coords = getMousePosInCanvas(canvas, e); 
    pencil.stroke(coords.x, coords.y, TwoTimesBigger);
  }  
});

$('#canvas').on('mouseup', function() {
  isDrawing = false;  
});

$('#canvas').on('mouseleave', function() {
  isDrawing = false;  
});

$('#pencil-simple').on('click', function() {
  pencil = new SimplePencil(ctx, ctxBigger); 
});

$('#pencil-sketchy').on('click', function() {
  pencil = new SketchyPencil(ctx, ctxBigger);
});

$('#clear-insert-backup').on('click', function() {
  var tempGlobalAlpha = ctx.globalAlpha;
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1; //For redrawing 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = tempGlobalAlpha;
});

/* PENCILS */
function SimplePencil(ctx, ctxBigger) {
    this.init(ctx, ctxBigger);
}

SimplePencil.prototype = {
    ctx: null, ctxBigger: null,
    previousX: null, previousY: null,
    
    init: function(ctx, ctxBigger) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.ctxBigger = ctxBigger;
    },
    stroke: function(x, y, TwoTimesBigger) {
      
        this.ctxBigger.strokeStyle = this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";

        /* Layer 1 */
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.previousX, this.previousY);
        this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.stroke();

        /* Layer 2 */
        this.ctxBigger.beginPath();
        this.ctxBigger.lineWidth = this.ctx.lineWidth * TwoTimesBigger;
        this.ctxBigger.moveTo( this.previousX * TwoTimesBigger, this.previousY * TwoTimesBigger );
        this.ctxBigger.lineTo( x * TwoTimesBigger, y * TwoTimesBigger);
        this.ctxBigger.closePath();
        this.ctxBigger.stroke();
        
      
        this.setPreviousCoords(x, y);
    },
    setPreviousCoords: function(x, y) {
        this.previousX = x;
        this.previousY = y;
    },
}

function SketchyPencil(ctx, ctxBigger) {
    this.init(ctx, ctxBigger);
}

SketchyPencil.prototype = {
    ctx: null, ctxBigger: null,
    previousX: null, previousY: null,

    init: function(ctx, ctxBigger) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.ctxBigger = ctxBigger;

        this.points = new Array();
        this.count = 0;
    },
    stroke: function(x, y, TwoTimesBigger) {
        var i, dx, dy, d;
        
        this.ctxBigger.strokeStyle = this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        this.ctxBigger.globalAlpha = this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;

        this.points.push([x, y]);
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
        this.ctxBigger.lineWidth = this.ctx.lineWidth * TwoTimesBigger;

        for (i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            dx = this.points[i][0] - this.points[this.count][0];
            dy = this.points[i][1] - this.points[this.count][1];
            d = dx * dx + dy * dy;

            if (d < 8000 && Math.random() > d / 4000) {
                this.ctx.beginPath();
                this.ctx.moveTo(this.points[this.count][0] + (dx * 0.3), this.points[this.count][1] + (dy * 0.3));
                this.ctx.lineTo(this.points[i][0] - (dx * 0.3), this.points[i][1] - (dy * 0.3));
                this.ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        
        for (i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            dx = this.points[i][0] - this.points[this.count][0];
            dy = this.points[i][1] - this.points[this.count][1];
            d = dx * dx + dy * dy;

            if (d < 8000 && Math.random() > d / 4000) {
                this.ctxBigger.beginPath();

                this.ctxBigger.moveTo( this.points[this.count][0] * TwoTimesBigger + (dx * (0.3 * TwoTimesBigger)), this.points[this.count][1] * TwoTimesBigger + (dy * (0.3 * TwoTimesBigger)) );
                this.ctxBigger.lineTo( this.points[i][0] * TwoTimesBigger - (dx * (0.3 * TwoTimesBigger)), this.points[i][1] * TwoTimesBigger - (dy * (0.3 * TwoTimesBigger )) );
                this.ctxBigger.stroke();
            } 
        }
    
        this.setPreviousCoords(x, y);
        this.count++;
    },
    setPreviousCoords: function(x, y) {
        this.previousX = x;
        this.previousY = y;
    },


}
```

```css
#canvas, #canvas2 {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="pencil-simple" value="Pencil simple">
<input type="button" id="pencil-sketchy" value="Pencil sketchy">
<input type="button" id="clear-insert-backup" value="Clear and insert backup in first square">    
<br>
    <p>Press <b>Pencil simple</b> or <b>Pencil sketchy</b> and start drawing in first square, second square only for backup 2x bigger than first, <i>After drawings with sketchy press <b>Clear and insert backup in first square</b> and you can see how first square not equal second.</i></p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Scale your context, do not scale coordinates by hand.

Comment: mhmm how i can do it :/